# Lookup editable only in edit mode

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, lookup

I created a custom lookup field, but when I add the visualforce page (the lookup) to my object page, he stays editable in the details page. I want he stays read only at details page and editable on new/edit object page. I already googled it but cant find anything similiar. Here is how he is now:

[image: Lookup field on details page]

Any ideia how I can put this read only (like the date, for example)?

Comment: I think it's not the same issue, but i also can't understand very well the propose of that question :/

Comment: The answer applies though, you should check it out.

Comment: Are you adding the visualforce page to a page layout? If so, then the duplicate @greenstork raised answers the question. If not, then please clarify the question.

Comment: @DanielHoechst Yes. But can you help me to apply the solution? I cant sew how to do it. I have to put the two lines in my visualforce code or in my apex code? Or I have to do something else?

Comment: My bad, it was my bad interpretation of the solution. Thanks :)